# JSF 2 and JSP 2

Tags: jsp, jsf, tomcat

Tomcat 7.0.x Spec versions:

- Servlet 3.0
- JSP 2.2
- EL 2.2.

Tomcat 6.0.x Spec versions:

- Servlet 2.5
- JSP 2.1

Is JSP 2.x the same of JSF (2.1)? Can I run a JSF 2.1 web applications in Tomcat 6?

Comment: See also our `[jsf]` tag wiki page: http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jsf/info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSP 2.x != JSF 2.x they are do different specs.

Yes, you can run a JSF 2.1 web app in Tomcat 6, in fact you can run JSF in any servlet container. 
Of course you also have to add the correct JSF libs if that is not already present in the servlet container of choice.

If you want to use EL expressions like `<h:commandButton action="#{myBean.myAction(myParameter)}"/>` you also have to make sure the EL 2.2 API and implementation JARs are available.

Comment: thank you!.. but i think that it would be usefull to add in the tomcat specifications which version of jsf supports, if JSP and JSF are different things.

Comment: @user1246780 `Tomcat` has nothing to do with `JSF`. It's just a *servlet container*. So, there is no reason to mention this in the specification. Theoretically, you should be able to plug in any `JSF` version to any *servlet container*.

Comment: EL 2.2 is **not** a requirement to get JSF 2.x to run.

Comment: @BalusC Right, but if you want to use EL expressions like `<h:commandButton action="#{myBean.myAction(myParameter)}"/>` you need EL 2.2 right?

Comment: That is in turn correct. But that is not required to get JSF 2.x to run.

Comment: @BalusC Thanks for the correction, updated answer to be more precise.

Answer (score 2):

You can't run a JSF 2.1 web app -directly- in Tomcat 6, as Tomcat only implements Servlet and JSP.

In order to run JSF apps on Tomcat, you need to add a JSF implementation (e.g. Mojarra) and in case of Tomcat 6 the newer EL jar if you want to use that (see e.g. http://javaevangelist.blogspot.com/2011/05/jsf-21x-on-tomcat-60.html).

It is however easier to use a server that already includes JSF (e.g. other people have already gone through the trouble of assembling this stuff). If you're a Tomcat fan, TomEE might be just for you. It's Tomcat with among others JSF already added. It's barely larger than Tomcat and is actually useable as a full stack solution right out of the box.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have all-in-one, JSF 2.x, JSP 2.x and many other things for java web development, you can use JBOSS application server, which provides all that stuff, and you don't have to worry about it.

Check out the last version of JBOSS (8), called The WildFly:

http://wildfly.org/downloads/